# Get total number of RAM bytes on windows

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ram

I'm trying to get the total number of RAM bytes. I'm not certain about the validity of my results.

My computer has 8GB of RAM. The control panel calls this *8.00GB (7.88 GB usable)*.

Using the [GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc300158%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call multiplied by 1000, I get 8388608000 bytes (assuming the kilobyte Windows refers to has indeed 1000 bytes).

When I run `wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory`, I get 8462008320 bytes.

When multiplying the call result by 1024 in case windows doesn't respect the conventions, I get 8589934592 bytes, which seems even less likely than the previous results.

In case it matters, I'm using two *Crucial Ballistix Tactical BLT2C4G3D1608ET3LX0CEU* memory modules advertized as 4GB per piece.

Comment: This limit is OS-dependent and application-bitness dependent. Please see [this chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Total installed memory has nothing to do with how much can be allocated in C. Per-process limits can range from 2GB to 8TB. It doesn't matter if your math works out, because the values that you are starting with are incorrect.

Comment: The conventions say that RAM is measured in multiples of 1024. Perhaps you're thinking of hard-disk manufacturers, who measure in multiples of 1000. 8462008320 / 1 GB is indeed equal to 7.88.

Comment: I see that 8589934592 was the value I'm looking for (all installed RAM in bytes). I thought a kilobyte was 1000 bytes on windows, but I was wrong. The wmic call seems to return the available memory, while I'm looking for the total amount. Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: That the amount of installed RAM has anything to do with how much you can allocate in a C program is a popular myth that hasn't been true for 21 years.  You are running on a demand-page virtual memory operating system.  You allocate virtual memory, RAM is only used when you actually access the memory.  A 32-bit program can allocate up to 2 gigabytes.  A 64-bit program can allocate as much as the paging file allows, usually much more than the amount of RAM.

Comment: _"I thought a kilobyte was 1000 bytes on windows"_ That's a new one! :)

Comment: I wasn't looking for the number of bytes that can be allocated in C, I was looking for the way to find that out, in C. It wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The result of GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory multiplied by 1024 was the answer I was looking for. This is the total number of RAM bytes installed on the system.